# RESTFULL API how to rewrite URL

Tags: php, .htaccess

Well to begin with I'm starting to write my own framework and in that framework im currently writing my own api, I have stumbled upon an issue where I hope I can get help with.

My url is currently:

> /api.php/Authorisation/Request?api_key=example-key&organisation_name=test-organisation

So my url is made out of a controller(authorisation) a method/action(Request) and with get parameters.

This Url has to be written to

> /Authorisation/Request/test-organisation/example-key

Any suggestions?

Comment: see this https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/introduction-to-url-rewriting/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved the issue:

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/ api.php/$1/$2?param=$3 [L]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/ api.php/$1/$2?param=$3&key=$4  [L]
```

But another issue occured
I want 1 more rewrite like this:
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/ api.php/$1/$2 [L]
But this gives this message:
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator at mail@localhost to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.